# Rails 3 ready to use in Production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is Rails 3 ready to use in Production?

I know is in beta (currently beta 3), but is it suitable to build a simple app using authentication (devise)? Or should I wait for a final version?

What is your opinion?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

37signals built their [Answers application](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/2122-launch-37signals-answers) using Rails 3, so by definition I'd say it's ready to use in production. Of course, your mileage may vary depending on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it'd depend on your definition of "production." There are still a bunch of [issues](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/milestones/27004-rails-3) that are being worked on but it doesn't seem like there are any showstoppers.